# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.models'; 'keras' is not a package

Tags: keras

[Keras program with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3wjE.jpg)

I am a beginner in Keras. I installed Anaconda with Python 3.6, then installed Tensorflow and ran some models I found on the Internet. Then I just found out about Keras which is just what I need to learn about Neural Networks. I installed Keras and it didn't have any errors. Then I found a short simple XOR model using Keras but it just didn't work and complained that it doesn't know what Keras is?? I hope someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 28):

The problem is that you have a file named "keras.py" and this shadows the real keras package. Don't do that, never name a python script the same as a package.

Solution is to rename your keras.py script into a different name.

Comment: This solves the error, should be selected as the best answer

Answer (score 6):

Because **keras is under tensorflow**, instead of:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

...try:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

Comment: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.model'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after changing the default python running on the linux to python 3 I had to change the first line of the executable python file environment:

from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

pretty simple "by one" error i guess